# Helm chart: Why environment variable defined in values.yml of helm chart not added to generated manifest?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to add environment variable to my wordpress helm chart. My values.yml file looks like :

```
#pvc wordpress
persistence:
  enabled: false

#pvc mariadb
mariadb:
  enabled: false 

externalDatabase:
  host: mysql
  port: 3306
  user: benighil@benighil 
  password: "SomePassword"
  database: bitnami_wordpress

extraEnv:
  - name: "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE" # <== THIS ONE
    value: /tmp/ca-cert

## Additional volume mounts
## Example: Mount CA file
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: ca-cert
    mountPath: /tmp

## Additional volumes
## Example: Add secret volume
extraVolumes:
 - name: ca-cert
   secret:
     secretName: ca-cert
```

But i generate a template using the following cmd :

```
helm template wp azure-marketplace/wordpress -n app --create-namespace -f values.yml > template.yml
```

and when i search the word : `WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE` in the file `template.yml`  :

`terminal: grep WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE template.yml` there is nothing returned !

I would like to know why ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct param is `extraEnvVars` not `extraEnv`

```
## @param extraEnvVars Array with extra environment variables to add to the WordPress container
## e.g:
## extraEnvVars:
##   - name: FOO
##     value: "bar"
```

so the values should be

```
extraEnvVars:
  - name: "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE" # <== THIS ONE
    value: /tmp/ca-cert
```

https://github.com/bitnami/azure-marketplace-charts/blob/master/bitnami/wordpress/values.yaml#L225

```
helm template wp azure-marketplace/wordpress -f values.yaml | grep "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE"
```

Comment: Hello @Adiii Thank you for your helpful reponse. I have another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263642/why-wordpress-helm-chart-not-able-to-connect-azure-mariadb-having-ssl-enabled?noredirect=1#comment129388768_73263642 ) related to this one. Any idea please ?

Comment: @Mohamed check my recent comment on the question