# Why WordPress Helm Chart not able to connect azure MariaDB having SSL enabled?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have managed MariaDB with SSL enabled deployed in Azure, and i created a service type "external" named "mysql" within my k8s cluster.

Then i created a secret like follwing :

```
kubectl create secret generic ca-cert --from-file=ca-cert=./BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem -n app
```

PS: where i got `BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem` from :

`wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem`

Then i deployed Wordpress:

```
helm template wp azure-marketplace/wordpress -n app --create-namespace -f values.yml
```

where values.yml looks like :

```
##############################PART1########################
#pvc wordpress
persistence:
  enabled: false

#pvc mariadb
mariadb:
  enabled: false 

externalDatabase:
  host: mysql
  port: 3306
  user: benighil@benighil 
  password: "SomePassword"
  database: bitnami_wordpress

##############################PART2########################
extraEnvVars:
  - name: "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE"
    value: /tmp/ca-cert

## Additional volume mounts
## Example: Mount CA file
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: ca-cert
    mountPath: /tmp

## Additional volumes
## Example: Add secret volume
extraVolumes:
 - name: ca-cert
   secret:
     secretName: ca-cert
```

But the pods logs gives :

```
wordpress 22:08:07.00 ERROR ==> Could not connect to the database
```

**NOTE1:** When i exec into pod, and do : `env | grep WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE` it gives : `WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE=/tmp/ca-cert` and when i do `cat /tmp/ca-cert` it gives its content normally.

**NOTE2:** The credentials are CORRECT, because when i desable SSL from MariaDB, and delete the whole PART2 from `values.yml` then it works fine!

Any help please?

Comment: I would avoid bitnami's stuff. Even when they work, their images are a mess ... Trusting a CA, there should be some initContainer running a "update-ca-certificates", while /etc/ssl/certs & /usr/local/share/ca-certificates are mounted from emptyDirs and shared with both initContainer & app container.

Comment: Hello @SYN, i have not understood, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: When you do an openssl s_client -connect from your wordpress container to mysql: I would assume you get a TLS error? If wordpress is not configured to ignore tls verification (https://serverfault.com/a/987740/293779), then you need to trust your CA. One way to do this would be with an initContainer, that would run "update-ca-certificates". I'm not sure how to do this in your context/with that helm chart: if you can't figure it out, you can ask on their github, or drop that chart and deploy wordpress yourself.

Comment: actually, the only certificate i have is : https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem (got it from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/concepts-ssl-connection-security )

Comment: ok. and? does openssl s_client -connect successfully verifies mysql server certificate?

Comment: debug logs can help, are you sure that the database is exist in azure mariadb? `image:
  debug: true` see the debug logs and it will help you to see the error

Comment: Yes, it is Mariadb in Azure.  How can use debug option ? could you please provide the whole command ?

Comment: add this in the value file and you should be able to see the debug logs

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/azure-marketplace-charts/blob/master/bitnami/wordpress/values.yaml#L91

Comment: make sure this `bitnami_wordpress` is exist in the mariadb

Comment: Seems like there are some other issue as well with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So make sure that the DB exist on the Azure MariaDB server and the second thing is that path is further used by the daemon `tmp` so certs should not be mounted here, somewhere where the daemon can read.

```
wordpress 04:19:09.91 INFO  ==> Persisting WordPress installation
/opt/bitnami/scripts/libpersistence.sh: line 51: /tmp/perms.acl: Read-only file system
```

so make the below changes and it should work

```
extraEnvVars:
  - name: "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_SSL_CA_FILE"
    value: /opt/bitnami/wordpress/tmp/ca-cert
  - name: WORDPRESS_ENABLE_DATABASE_SSL
    value: "yes"

## Additional volume mounts
## Example: Mount CA file
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: ca-cert
    mountPath: /opt/bitnami/wordpress/tmp
```

or you will have to set extra params for the same path

```
  containerSecurityContext:
    enabled: true
    privileged: false
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
    ## Requires mounting an `extraVolume` of type `emptyDir` into /tmp
    ##
    readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
    capabilities:
      drop:
        - ALL
```